# Run Bash script from OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Is it possible to run a Bash script from OCaml like from Java or from PHP? I know that we can [use OCaml as a scripting language](https://blog.janestreet.com/ocaml-as-a-scripting-language/) but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [OCaml documentation](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Sys.html#VALcommand):

```ml
val command : string -> int
```

So if you want to call a script from OCaml, do this:

```ml
let status = Sys.command "./myexecutable.sh" in
Printf.printf "status = %d\n" status
```

Feel free to do what you want with the exit code.

Answer (score 6):

Just in case you are interested in collecting the output of the bash script,

```
let () =
  (* Just using pstree as an example, you can pick something else *)
  let ic = Unix.open_process_in "pstree" in
  let all_input = ref [] in
  try
    while true do
      all_input := input_line oc :: !all_input
    done
  with
    End_of_file ->
    (* Just an example, you can do something else here *)
    close_in ic;
    List.iter print_endline !all_input
```

Comment: I think you mean `oc` on line 7. Also, what's the best way to get access to `Unix`, do I just put `#load "unix.cma"` at the top of the file?

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is the `Sys` module (http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Sys.html).

`Sys.command` might be one way to do what you want.

If this is not enough, then you may want to take a look at what the `Unix` has to offer (http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html).